# Spring cloud contract with common contract repository

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I Created a sperate repository to store the contract as descibed in this link:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/main/samples/standalone/contracts

In the producer side, I added the generated jar of contract as follow:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <contractsMode>LOCAL</contractsMode>
        <contractDependency>
            <groupId>com.example.standalone</groupId>
            <artifactId>contracts</artifactId>
        </contractDependency>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I execute the maven install, this doesn't generate the contracts verifier classes in the target folder. any help?
Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this repo https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/main/producer_with_external_contracts ?

Comment: I used the contract generate in this sample (beer-contracts) in the producer side but there is no generate classes in the target directory

Comment: beer-contract contains only contract definitions - it does not contain classes in the traget directory. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve then

Comment: I've added an answer to your questoin. Can you please mark this as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the sample in spring-cloud-contract-samples repo [producer with external contracts](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/main/producer_with_external_contracts)

The [beer contracts](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/main/beer_contracts) folder contains only contract definitions - it will not generate any test classes.

This project [producer with external contracts](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/main/producer_with_external_contracts)  will generate test classes from the contracts defined in this [beer contracts](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/main/beer_contracts) folder.